# How does a missing boolean operator still compile?

Tags: scala, chisel

I have code like this:

```
val pop: Bool = (
  (fsm === Fsm.None && canPop) ||
  (fsm === Fsm.Some && canPop && fooBar)
  (fsm === Fsm.Other && canPop && dragonFruit) ||
  (fsm === Fsm.Mom && canPop))
```

`fsm` is a ChiselEnum based state machine and the other signals are just Bools. There is a missing `||` on the second statement line (after fooBar). This compiles and runs, although causes a bug in the behavior. My question is... why does this compile? This doesn't seem like valid syntax. Is it?

Please help me understand this. I just spent numerous days debugging a large circuit to find this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Correct Answer**

The problem is that this is a bit extract.  Chisel lets you do `foo(bar)` to extract the bit at index `bar` out of `foo`.  The above code, as written, is a bit extract even though the user wants it to be a mistake.

Unfortunately, this is a known gotcha and it's not reasonable to error on this without false positives while still allowing users to use the `()` syntax for bit extracts.

**Incorrect Original Answer**

It's valid syntax per Scala rules.  What's going on here is that the code is really two statements, but the indentation is confusing.  It's equivalent to:

```scala
val foo = a + b  // Create an immutable value equal to "a + b".
  c + d          // A bare statement that adds "c + d", but doesn't use the result.
```

Or infamous C bugs like:

```c
if (cond)
  foo();
  bar(); // bar() is always executed, but the indentation is confusing.
```

Usually this is the type of thing that you'd notice due to a code formatter or via linting.  However, the problem is common to almost every language.

Setting up [Scalafmt](https://scalameta.org/scalafmt/) for your project may help.

Comment: But I'm using an outer bracket around all the lines!

Comment: Ack... missed that. I'll update my answer. The problem is that, as written, it's doing a bit extract.  E.g., `(a || b)(c ||d)`.  However, the line break is confusing.  This is a known gotcha, but there's no good way to fix it while still enabling the `()`-style extraction syntax. :(